# how to add in binary

Tags: binary, addition, digital-design

[image]

I don't understand when 100 appear in add what I should  do. what the carry for the next step? They are marked with red and blue colors

Answer (score 2):

Let's go step by step:

```
  000011
  001101
  011011
+ 110110
--------
```

First we add the values in the 1's column: `1 + 1 + 1 + 0 = 11`. We carry the 2's column of the result and continue:

```
      1
  000011
  001101
  011011
+ 110110
--------
       1
```

Now we add the values of the 2's column (including the carry): `1 + 1 + 0 + 1 + 1 = 100`. I think this is where your confusion started, because the sum has 3 columns instead of 2. We can just carry both extra columns:

```
    10
  000011
  001101
  011011
+ 110110
--------
      01
```

Continuing on to add the values of the 4's column: `0 + 0 + 1 + 0 + 1 = 10`. We have a `1` to carry over to the 8's column, but there's already a carried `1` there! So we add the two carries: `1 + 1 = 10`. Essentially, we shift the carry in the 8's column over the 16's column:

```
   10
  000011
  001101
  011011
+ 110110
--------
     001
```

We add the 8's column (`0 + 0 + 1 + 1 + 0 = 10`) and once again we have a "collision" of our carried values. So just like before, we add the carries, resulting in a "shift":

```
  10
  000011
  001101
  011011
+ 110110
--------
    0001
```

Add the 16's column and carries:

```
  10
   000011
   001101
   011011
+  110110
---------
    00001
```

After adding the 32's column:

```
  1
   000011
   001101
   011011
+  110110
---------
   100001
```

All that remains is our carry in the 64's column:

```
   000011
   001101
   011011
+  110110
---------
  1100001
```

Comment: this is for unsigned; "carry" is not typically used for that; we also need to know the range/width